# Ansible connectivity from Control Host to Remote Host : Alternate to Passwordless SSH

Tags: ansible

We are in the midway of implementing Ansible CI for app deployment. For connecting the Remote host from Control Host , we used passwordless SSH authentication (by adding SSH key to authorized_keys).

But with recent changes, Unix team not allowing this any more on higher env as corporate unix policy. So have to use the password way.

The user with which Ansible running & connecting to Remote machine is a sudo user & does not have a password for itself.

So in this case, how do we connect from Control Host to Remote host, without the SSH key?

Comment: You set a password for the user. Then you ask the Unix team why they have made such an insane change. This will break so many things and reduce security.

Comment: Apparently they have done it for Security purpose, which they derive via some wired logic..

Comment: They are very very wrong